# Case insensitive expectations in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, case, rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mocks to expect a call. There is a single parameter which is a string. But I'm not bothered about the case of the string. I want the test to pass even if the case is wrong. So I'm doing the following:

```
//expect log message to be called with a string parameter.  
//We want to ignore case when verifying so we use a constraint 
//instead of a direct parameter

Expect.Call(delegate { logger.LogMessage(null); })
      .Constraints(Is.Matching<string>(x => x.ToLower()=="f2"));
```

It seems a bit long-winded. Is there a more sensible way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

```
// arrange
var loggerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILogger>();

// act
loggerStub.LogMessage("f2");

// assert
loggerStub.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.LogMessage(Arg<string>.Matches(
        s => string.Equals(s, "f2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    ))
);
```

If you don't care about parameters but just the method call:

```
loggerStub.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.LogMessage(null),
    x => x.IgnoreArguments()
);
```

Comment: I think he wants to verify the string, but doesn't care about case.  Neither one of these does that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the AAA format that @Darin suggests (or similar).  I think it's more concise, but you'll still have to use the same basic constraint for case insensitive matching, I think.  A helper method can make this more readable.

```
 private bool CaseInsensitive( string s, string t )
 {
      return string.Equals( s, t, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
 }

 var loggerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Logger>();

 loggerMock.Expect( l => l.LogMessage( Arg<string>.Matches( s => CaseInsensitive( s, "f2" ))));

 classUnderTest.MethodUnderTest();

 loggerMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```